# Fast Fourier transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have found a bit of code in MATLAB:

```
y = fft(y, nfft);
```

Where y is a 512x443 two-dimensional array and nfft = 512.

I thought that *fft* is for a one-dimensional array and for a two-dimensional array there should be fft2, but fft is working. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/fft.html) (emphasis mine):

> Y = fft(x) returns the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of vector x, computed with a fast Fourier transform (FFT) algorithm.
>
> If the input X is a matrix, Y = fft(X) returns *the Fourier transform of each column* of the matrix.

Comment: Can I calculate the phase difference of two vectors using fft?
I need to know the sub-pels displacement.

Answer (score 3):

`fft` actually takes an (optional) third argument: `dim`. This tells it which dimension to perform the FFT on.

If you don't specify it, `dim` will default to the "first nonsingleton dimension". So you're getting a one-dimensional FFT of all the columns of your two-dimensional array.

Comment: But it's possible to do real 2d fft, with `fft2`

Comment: @oli That's right. It's also interesting to note that the 2D FT should give the same result as performing a 1D FT along each dimension.